# The QFileDialog is not showing correctly after I open a video with OpenNI

Tags: qt, video, openni

I want to create in QT a video player for OpenNI2 videos. I successfully  reproduce the videos, the problem is when I want to open a second video the QFileDialog windows appears incomplete and is not really responding.

```
void WVideoPlayer::on_btnOpen_clicked(){
QString fileName =QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open File"),
                                         "./",
                                         tr("Files (*.oni)"));

if ( fileName.isNull() == true )
{
    fileName="recording.oni";
}

emit openVideoSource(ab::SOURCE_FILE,fileName);
if(timer!=0){
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), ui->lblVideoScreen, SLOT(animate()));
}
cout<<"end on_btnOpen_clicked"<<endl;
}
```

[image: The Dialog showing nothing, some times it show an small part]

Comment: Is that really the code?  `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName` is a static member according to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileName).

Comment: yes, I think I found an example like that, so I also change it, but the problem remains